# When I do an Ajax request and the json data has a # in it the data turns to 1

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

When `message_val[0] = 'test#'` The message that gets json encoded turns to 1. If `message_val[0] = 'test'` The message is test. I think it is a json issue but im not sure how to fix it.

```
function send_message(result) {
  message_val = [];
  var conf = document.getElementById("onconf");
  message_val.push(document.getElementById("message").value);
  var phrase = makeid(5)
  var result = prompt("You are about to send " + saved_num_of_cust + " text messages. Please type the following phrase to confirm: " + phrase);
  if (result == phrase) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        onconf.innerHTML = "<p>Confirmation Success sending " + saved_num_of_cust + " messages </p>";
        onconf.style.display = "block";
        onconf.style.color = "#97e46e";
      }
    }

    message_val.push(id_data);
    message_val = JSON.stringify(message_val);
    console.log(message_val);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "sendtext.php?q=" + message_val, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  } else {
    console.log("FAILED");
    onconf.innerHTML = "<p>Confirmation failed please try again</p>";
    onconf.style.display = "block";
    onconf.style.color = "#e4726e";

  }
}
```

Edit:
The 1 value is after it is `JSON.stringify'ed`

Full html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Editorial by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>[[*pagetitle]]</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/pages/assets/css/main.css" />
<style>
.ignore_class{all:unset;}
#onconf{
display:none;
}
</style>
<script>
async function time_keeper() {
        //var date = new Date();
        //console.log(date.getHours()); // Fri Jun 17 2022 11:27:28 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
        var button = document.getElementById("send_btn");

        while (1 == 1) {
            var date = new Date();
            var hour = date.getHours();
            
            if (hour >= 20 || hour < 7) {
                
                button.disabled = true;
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 6000));
                continue;

            }else{
                button.disabled = false;
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 6000));
                continue;
            }

        }
    }
</script>

<script>
        var id_data = "[[++API_id]]";
        var saved_num_of_cust = "";
        function load_function(){
time_keeper();
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    //console.log(this.responseText);
                    const num_of_cust = document.getElementById("num_of_customers");
                    num_of_cust.innerText = "Number of Text Message Recipients: " + this.responseText;
                    saved_num_of_cust = this.responseText;
console.log(this.responseText);






                }
            }
            
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "onload.php?q=" + id_data, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
function send_message(result) {
message_val = [];
var conf = document.getElementById("onconf");
//var message_val = document.getElementById("message").value;
      message_val.push(document.getElementById("message").value);
      //console.log(message_val);
      //alert("Are you sure you would like to send " + saved_num_of_cust + " text messages");
      var phrase = makeid(5)
      var result = prompt("You are about to send " + saved_num_of_cust + " text messages. Please type the following phrase to confirm: " + phrase);
      //console.log(result);
      if(result == phrase){
          var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                  //console.log(this.responseText);
                  //const num_of_cust = document.getElementById("num_of_customers");
                  //num_of_cust.innerText = "Number of Text Message Recipients:" + this.responseText;
                  console.log(this.responseText);
onconf.innerHTML = "<p>Confirmation Success sending " + saved_num_of_cust + " messages </p>";
onconf.style.display = "block";
onconf.style.color = "#97e46e";






              }
          }
//var company_id = "[[!getResourceField? &id=`2` &field=`company id` &processTV=`1`]]";
message_val.push(id_data);
message_val = JSON.stringify(message_val);
          xmlhttp.open("GET", "sendtext.php?q=" + message_val, true);
          xmlhttp.send();


      }else{
console.log("FAILED");
onconf.innerHTML = "<p>Confirmation failed please try again</p>";
onconf.style.display = "block";
onconf.style.color = "#e4726e";

      }

      //}


  }
  function makeid(length) {
      var result           = '';
      var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghIjkLmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
      var charactersLength = characters.length;
      for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
          result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() *
              charactersLength));
      }
      return result;
  }

  //console.log(makeid(5));

    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload" onload = "load_function()">

        <!-- Wrapper -->
            <div id="wrapper">

                <!-- Main -->
                    <div id="main">
                        <div class="inner">

                            <!-- Header -->
                                <header id="header">
                                    <center><a href="[[~3]]" class="logo"><img src="[[!getResourceField? &id=`2` &field=`BusinessLogo` &processTV=`1`]]"></a></center>
                                </header>

                            <!-- Content -->                                   


                            
                                <section>

                                    <!-- Content -->

                                <section id="selecticon">

                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    [[$bulk_message_form]]
                                    
                                </section>

                                    <hr class="major" />



                                </section>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                <!-- Sidebar -->
                [[$SideBar]]

            </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="themes/pages/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="themes/pages/assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="themes/pages/assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="themes/pages/assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="themes/pages/assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

The below code belongs where the [[$bulk_message_form]] is. Our CMS allows us to use chunks of html to make pages more modular.

```
<style>
    .cc_container{

        text-align: center;
    }
    .ta{
        resize: none;
        margin:auto;

        width: 50%;
        height: 25vh;
    }
    .ta:focus{outline: none;}
    .cc{
        text-align: center;
        position:relative;
        /*right: 26%;*/
        /*bottom: 72%;*/
        bottom:5px;
        right:5px;

        color:darkgrey;
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
        -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Standard */
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        padding-top:5px;
    }
    .product{
        resize:none;
        width: 50%;
        height: 25vh;
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
        -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Standard */
        margin:auto;

    }
    .product:focus{outline: none;}
    .popup{
        display:none;
        background: inherit;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.10);
        bottom: 28%;
        right: 22.4%;
        backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
        z-index: 10;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px darkgrey;
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
        -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */
        user-select: none; /* Standard */
        height: 12%;
        width: 10%;
        word-wrap: break-word;



    }
    .text_inside{
        padding: 5px;
        color: #4F4F4FFF;
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.5vh;
        margin-top: auto;

    }
    body{
        text-align:center;
    }


</style>
<h1>Bulk Text Message Center<sup><sup style = "color:#808080FF; font-size: 50%">BETA</sup></sup></h1>
<p id = "num_of_customers"></p>
<div id = "onconf">

</div>
<div class="cc_container">
    <textarea id = "msg_area" class = "ta" onkeyup="cc()"></textarea>
    <p id = "cc" class = "cc">0/160</p>
    <p>Finalized message:</p>
    <textarea class = "product" id = "message" readonly></textarea>
    <p id = "cost_line">estimated cost:</p>

    <div class = "popup" id = "popup">
        <p class="text_inside"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<button type = "button" id = "send_btn" onclick = "send_message()">Send Message</button>

<script>
    var cost_val = 0.02;
    function cc(){
        var cc_tb = document.getElementById("msg_area")
        var character_count = cc_tb.value.length + 28;
        var cc_box = document.getElementById("cc");
        var product_box = document.getElementById("message");
        var cost = document.getElementById("cost_line");
        var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
        //format count
        cc_box.innerText = character_count + "/160";
        //adds reply
        product_box.innerText = cc_tb.value + ". Reply STOP to unsubscribe."
        char_product = Math.floor((character_count-1)/160);
        console.log(char_product);
        if (char_product >= 1){
            cost_val = 0.02 * (char_product + 1);
            //changes character count to red
            cc_box.style.color = "#e4726e";
            //displays popup
            popup.style.display = "block";
            //sets the message of the popup
            popup.innerText = "After the message reaches 160 characters long it will cost $" + cost_val + " per text.";
            //updates cost value


            popup.innerText = "After the message reaches 160 characters long it will cost $" + cost_val + " per text.";

            //updated estimated cost
            cost.innerText = "estimated cost: $" + (cost_val * saved_num_of_cust).toFixed(2);
        }else{
            //hides popup
            popup.style.display = "none";
            //changes color of character count
            cc_box.style.color = "darkgray";
            cost_val = 0.02;
            cost.innerText = "estimated cost: $" + (cost_val * saved_num_of_cust).toFixed(2);
        }


    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you see 1?  From console.log(message_val)?

Comment: Yes. after it is `JSON.stringify'ed`

Comment: Not sure how message_val can be anything but an array.  Can you add the html to the question and the missing function makeid.

Comment: In your example you refer to **id_data** but no where in the example are you declaring it or setting its value.

Comment: I just updated the question. The code is a little odd because of the way our CMS works.

Comment: @imvain2 It is defined in a function that runs on load. You should be able to see it now that I updated the question with the full page